# javascript how to get html style's custom attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html element with some inline styles plus on custom css property.
now i can access every style attribute but not my custom style property.

here is my code.

```
<img id="myimg" class="ImgClass" style="overfolow:hidden;position:absolute;mycustomProp:100;top:15;left:20">
```

here i cannot get mycustomProp.

Any help?

Comment: quick note: "overfolow" -> "overflow"

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/attributes-and-custom-properties

Comment: Avinash Babu i can access custom attribute, but its not my question my question is how to get custom style property.

Comment: There is no custom style property. There is just an invalid CSS declaration that is ignored by a browser when it parses a style sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/phrjwgxk/

```
alert(getCustomStyle("myimg","mycustomProp"));


function getCustomStyle(theId,theStyle) {
    var styles=document.getElementById(theId).getAttribute("style").split(';');
    var astyle;
    for(var i=0;i<styles.length;i++) {
        astyle=styles[i].split(':');
        if(astyle[0]==theStyle) return (astyle[1]);
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: I was just done it manually like you did. anyways thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("myimg").getAttribute("style")` to retrieve the attribute.

`document.getElementById("myimg").setAttribute("style",<string>)` can be used to change it.

Comment: its sends the whole mixed array, mean it treat every single char as array element.

Answer (score 0):

check

`$("#myDiv").hasAttribute(name)`

get

`$("#myDiv").getAttribute(name)`

set

`$("#myDiv").setAttribute(name)`

delete

`$("#myDiv").removeAttribute(name)`